# Sending a str list by email with python

Tags: python, email, flask

I'm programming a web app with Flask and I have this problem:
In `data` I've a list of str values and I define:

```
    msg="\n".join(data)
```

Then, when I try to do

```
    server.sendmail("1@example.com", "2@example.com", msg)
```

I have an error. It´s very strange because if I only send a list with str elements which haven't got spacing characters, it works perfectly.
The error is:

> ```
> Internal Server Error
> ```
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Can you show  'data' and also what works and doesn't work?

Comment: Please, post the actual traceback info

Comment: I've solved it, it seems like it was a problem with the ' character I don't know why exactly. Thanks for your time!

Comment: turn on the debugger : `app.run(debug=True)` or `app.debug = True ; app.run() ` then you can see internal server errors ...